# How to open a PDF file inside a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I need to let my MVC website visitors to open PDF files within it and extract some information out of them. Is there any way to do that?
[image: see the following picture]

Answer (score 1):

Let `divPdf` be the required `div` then you can [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) the file using:

```
 <div id="divPdf">
       <embed src="fileName.pdf" />
 </div>
```

Comment: This is download PDF, instead of displaying the PDF inside the browser DIV.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ConvertToSwf(string pdfPath, string swfPath, int page)
{
    try
    {
        string exe =  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("PDF2SWF/pdf2swf.exe");
        if (!File.Exists(exe))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Can not find: " + exe);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(" -o \"" + swfPath + "\"");//output
        sb.Append(" -z");
        sb.Append(" -s flashversion=9");//flash version
        sb.Append(" -s disablelinks");
        sb.Append(" -p " + "1" + "-" + page);//page range
        sb.Append(" -j 100");//Set quality of embedded jpeg pictures to quality. 0 is worst (small), 100 is best (big). (default:85)
        sb.Append(" \"" + pdfPath + "\"");//input
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = sb.ToString();
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public static int GetPageCount(string pdfPath)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfPath);
        int length = buffer.Length;
        if (buffer == null)
            return -1;
        if (buffer.Length <= 0)
            return -1;
        string pdfText = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx1 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches = rx1.Matches(pdfText);
        return matches.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

http://www.swftools.org/

PDF2Swf.exe  can convert 【.pdf】 to 【.swf】 then display in your page
it may be work!

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<div>
    <iframe src="[Full path of your PDF file]" ></iframe>
</div>
```